# Nexus running with JettyServer will not start

Tags: jetty, nexus

Firstly please forgive my ignorance here - it's the first time I have asked a question on here and I am definitely out of my league.  I have two staff members who would normally maintain this application but both are completely unavailable for some time yet.

We run an instance of Sonatype Nexus 2.11.1-01 using JettyServer on and Ubuntu instance on AWS.  This morning we attempted to take snapshot of the instance and the process froze up completely.  We had to cancel this and since then Nexus will not run.  There is simply a message "Nexus OSS failed to run".

I've tried this as difference users and oddly there don't appear to be any entries in the logs for the last 4 hours or so, which is around the time it initially stopped working.  Since then despite many attempts at restarting there is nothing in them, unless I am missing some stored somewhere else.

Again I apologise for any ignorance on my part but this isn't normally my forte and it is really important I get this running again.  Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This doesn't seem like a programming or development question.  Stackoverflow isn't the right place for this.  Best if you use [serverfault.com](http://serverfault.com/) for this question.

Comment: OK, sorry about that Joakim and thanks for pointing me in a more appropriate direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that during the process of creating the snapshot on AWS, the /var/run/nexus directory was deleted.  This is pretty frightening - haven't actually got to the bottom of that, but we have created that directory again and given ownership to nexus:nexus, restarted and everything is working again.